# Error when trying to integrate JavaFX with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, javafx

I'm trying to integrate javaFX with Hibernate using Maven on Intellij. When I first created a Hibernate project, and added some JavaFX dependencies to it. I ran and

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Then I decided to add "module-info.java" file to the project, this happened as described below . I already tried to trace to the end of this error on the right this time, tried every possible solutions... and finally it was just a dead end for me. So I has been wondering if I did anything wrong?

Error happened after module-info.java added:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:345)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:337)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:230)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:141)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:96)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:158)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:124)
at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.4.18.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
at myModule/controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:44)
... 58 more
```

Edited: I'm exploring, reading some projects on Github and find it may relevant to module in Java 9? I see they separate their code into modules and in each module it like...  independent maven projects with its own pom.xml file, one has only javafx dependency; another has only hibernate dependency.

[Here is the project I'm reading](https://github.com/Shehanka/RentLio)

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace of your exception as a text.

Comment: no screenshots of text please, they are unreadable and unsearchable. And: _tried every possible solutions_ you are aware that this is logically wrong :)

Comment: Pardon me this is my first time posting a question on StackOverFlow. I'll notice next time

Comment: Even in the project i'm reading I got that error too... Can someone help me?